# How to access the string content of a class?

Tags: python, html, selenium, class

I'm trying to access each string value inside a span for every class of the web page.
Here is how the html looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbqj5.jpg.

I would like to access the "1.53 SKILL" price value.

Here is my trial:

```
price_class= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('has-tooltip')

for price in price_class:
    i = 0 
    price = price_class[i].text
    i += 0
    print(''+price+'')
```

Since i actually need to access every price value of the page i thought that by doing a for loop parsing every element in the class would return the "1.53 SKILL" like string value.
It actually doesn't and returns some strange characters.

How can i access that string value ?

Comment: Please post all of the code as text, you can use ```html to format the code.

Comment: What is the actual "strange" character you are receiving?

Comment: @Prophet My bad, it doesn't return anything actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. from the picture you provided I see the class name is  `has-tooltip` (with space   at the beginning)
2. your loop `for price in price_class:` already returns the element you can retrieve the text from with no need to perform

```py
i = 0 
price = price_class[i].text
i += 0
```

But this will also present you the "Price" string.
To remove it and the `:` you can do this:

```
price_class= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class=" has-tooltip"]')

for price in price_class:
    price_price_txt = price.find_element_by_xpath(".//strong").text    
    total_txt = price.text
    final_txt = total_txt.replace(price_price_txt, '')
    final_txt = final_txt.replace(':', '')
    print(final_txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! actually it's kinda strange but by using ' has-tooltip' with the space a the beginning it throws an "InvalidSelectorException". I tried to WebDriverWait because i thought that it wasn't loaded yet but it doesn't work regardless.

Comment: I see... Please see if xpath selector as I changed will work?

Comment: Website is down at the moment. I'll let you know as soon as I can. Thank you for you help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try BeautifulSoup and `get_text`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(price_class[i], 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```